# How can I use the filter function in jquery to filter a group of data inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having cards and inside of them are data from a database. These cards are enclosed in a div called **search**. I'm trying to filter the cards with the data inside them and output the cards with the same data used to filter. For example each card has different names and I want the card having the same address, I want those cards to be displayed per **keypress**. This is the code I currently have

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#search card").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id = "search">


        <?php foreach($query as $row):  ?>

            <div class="card-deck" >
                 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card"><center>
                        <a href="testingsite.dev/tenant/<?php echo $row->userID; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><img src = "https://admin.orangesuites.ph/static/uploads/<?php echo $row->profile_pic; ?>" width="209" height="180" ></a>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title"><?php echo $row->firstName . ' ' . $row->lastName; ?></h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Room Number: <?php echo $row->bldg_num . '-' . $row->room_num; ?><br>
                                    Price: <?php echo $row->price; ?><br>
                                    Move In Date: <?php
                                    $move_in = new DateTime($row->move_in_date);
                                    echo $move_in->format('F j, Y');
                                    ?><br>
                                     Move Out Date: <?php
                                    $move_out = new DateTime($row->move_out_date);
                                    echo $move_out->format('F j, Y');
                                    ?><br>
                                    Pending Amount: <?php echo $pending_total[$row->merge_id]; ?><br>
                                    Contact Number: <?php echo $row->phone; ?><br><br><br>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">

                             </div>
                        </center></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: You are missing a `.` in `$("#search card")`, it should be `$("#search .card")`

Comment: It would help of you post the HTML code rather the php.

Comment: thats the code im having. the php is only used for calling data from the database @Eddie

Comment: I understand that. But I'm what I'm saying it would be easier for other users to have the *generated* html code so that they can just copy and paste it on jsfiddle to test and suggest a solution :)